What is the password for jovyan user in jupyter lab docker container?
I have pulled the jupyter/datascience-notebook:latest image from docker hub and launched an instance container of it. I logged into the container through bash. Now i want to restart the server itself because i have made some modifications to a config file and need it to be picked up by the server; i am configuring nbgrader by the way.
I have found a command in a stackoverflow answer, to restart the server: it says sudo initctl restart jupyter-server --no-wait. Now when i type that command it asks me for a password for the user *jovyan" which i don't know.
So how to come around it ?

I think you are looking for is in the links here. See for more background either here to use something like docker run -p 8888:8888 --user root -e GRANT_SUDO=yes jupyter/base-notebook or here where it says use docker exec -it -u root container_id bashto tell it to not ask for a password for the password to use for running the sudo command. ...

 Here says much the same thing as the earlier posts I referenced above but I would see what the linked documentation (from my comment above) for the most current says. Elsewhere this thread it says the default password for jovyan on some system is jupyter. That may be worth a try but I think it was for a specific JupyterHub and not the docker stack you have. Also see here ...

 where I think you can look into things if you are doing this a different way and have set a password. I think. I believe though the earlier stuff is what you are looking for at this time.

I tried it and it is no longer asking for password. Although i haven't still got the initially intended result (picking up config file after restart). I don't know if it really restarted the server or not. I also don't know if it is possible to even restart running jupyter from a container.. @Wayne

Regardless usong user command in docker run, we can use the command to switch user.
docker exec -it -u root <container_name_or_id> /bin/bash

Here's the image, docker push codecrash/jupyter-notebook:latest which does not required any passord but in case you need it, it's root.
